# Android Studio - View works immediately, not after I take my hand off

Tags: android, touch-event

I am new to Android Studio. I would be glad if you help. when I click on a picture and I can't take action on the picture until I take my hand. After pulling, text toast works. Let it work as soon as I print the pictures. thanks

##### Here's the code

```
public static class PassThroughButton extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {

        private Bitmap mBitmap;
    
        public PassThroughButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                int color = mBitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(),
                        (int) event.getY());
                if (color == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    
    
    
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            if (w == 0 && h == 0 && oldw == 0 && oldh == 0) {
                super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            } else {
                final StateListDrawable bkg = (StateListDrawable) getBackground();
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        ((BitmapDrawable) bkg.getCurrent()).getBitmap(),
                        getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: WHat toast?  There's no toast in your code.  What is this code supposed to do?  You need to provide more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: kusura bakmayın ingilizce bilmiyorum..translator kullanıyorum. yukarıdaki programda resim üzerine tıklatınca hemen işlem yapmıyor. elimi çekince işlem yapıyor. ben resme tıklayınca  hemen çalışsın istiyorum.

Comment: Aşağıdaki kodu nasıl değiştirirsiniz hemen tıklayacaktır.

genel boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent olayı)